# How can i show source code of moodle webserivce

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

In which file or under which folder path (moodle folder) can I get the source code of the web service? THX

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of core web service definitions in **lib/db/services.php**

https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/lib/db/services.php

Each service will contain **class name and method name**, you can find the source of that particular service in mentioned class and method.

Other third-party plugin webservices will be defined in that plugins folder (**plugin/db/services.php**) file.